# Adding a style to JavaScript element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a 2 column layout in my JavaScript code. 
This is the CSS that I need to apply to my JS code:

```
div#theLeft {
  clear:both;
  width:15%;
  float:left;
}

div#theRight {
  width:83%;
  float:right;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  padding-right:30px;
}
```

How do I apply this to my JavaScript elements in my .js file?

```
myText = (" 
<html>\n<head>\n<title>Resume</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n");

myText += (userName+"<br>");  
myText += (address+ " / " +phoneNo +"<br>");
myText += ("<hr width 70%>");

myText += ("PERSONAL\n DETAILS<br>");
myText += ( +personalData+ "<br>");

myText += ("CAREER\n OBJECTIVES<br>"); 
myText += ( +careerObj+"<br>");    

myText += ("EDUCATION<br>");
myText += ( +edubackgrnd+ "<br>");

myText += ("EMPLOYMENT\n EXPERIENCE<br>");    
myText += (fromDate+ " - " +toDate+"<br>");
myText += (experience +"<br>");

myText += (fromDate1+ " - " +toDate1+"<br>");
myText += (experience1 +"<br>");

myText += (fromDate2+ " - " +toDate2+"<br>");
myText += (experience2 +"<br>");

myText += (fromDate3+ " - " +toDate3+"<br>");
myText += (experience3 +"<br>");

myText += ("CHARACTER \n REFERENCES<br>");
myText += ("Upon request<br>");

myText += ("BUSINESS \n REFERENCE<br>");
myText += (busRef);

myText += ("</body>\n</html>");

flyWindow = window.open('about:blank','myPop','width=1000,height=500,left=200,top=200');
flyWindow.document.write(myText);
```

Here is my JS. If I am understanding correctly, I can add html tags in JavaScript between quotes (""); correct?

Comment: You really need to explain what is it you need a bit better. You can use javascript to add a class to each element. Unfortunately, the people around here are the most unforgiving when it comes to helping with vague answers.

Comment: Your question seems to reflect a misunderstand of frontend web technologies. CSS is used to style your HTML "code." JavaScript is used to add business logic or behavior to your page. I'll provide an attempt at an answer below.

Comment: Sorry, very beginner at JavaScript.

Comment: No worries. Gotta start somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for being understanding. I updated my post with my JavaScript code. My question is if I could add <div /> tags to the user's input so that it will display floated to the right of the categories.

Comment: May I ask why you are creating all of your HTML in your javascript code?

Answer (score 1):

In order for that CSS to be applied to a particular HTML file it needs to be included between `<style></style>` tags somewhere. As an alternative (and much better practice) your CSS should be stored in a separate .css file and included using a `<link>` tag like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='static/style.css'>
```

As a further alternative, if what you meant by including JS in the question was that you want to apply that style dynamically, like when an event takes place on your page, you can do that by using jQuery. There are certainly native ways to do it but, for this sort of thing, I still prefer jQuery.

```
$("div#theRight")
    .css("width", "83%")
    .css("padding", "float:right")
    .css("padding-bottom", "20px")
    .css("padding-right", "30px");
```

Finally, the best way would be to include a .css file as mentioned above that applies you styles to elements of a certain class. Then, when your event takes place, add or remove that class from your element(s) to apply or remove those styles dynamically.

```
$("div#theRight").addClass("myClass");

$("div#theRight").removeClass("myClass");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This makes a little bit of sense...my question is how to generate the users output in a 2 column layout. So for example, from my code I want "Personal Details" to float to the right and the info from the var personalData to float to the left. Like I said I am at the super beginner level of JavaScript so I don't know how to connect the jQuery that you provided to my JavaScript code.